# CROSS JOINS or UNION ALL with complex business rules?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, union, cross-join

I'm creating this since I'm curious about the answer.

I have a table with essentially 4 columns: GroupA, GroupB, Tag and value.

| GroupA | Group B | Tag | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | E | PrefixYear3.SubCategoryASubSubcategoryA | 100 |
| B | F | PrefixYear3.SubCategoryBSubSubcategoryA | A |
| C | G | PrefixYear4.SubCategoryCSubSubcategoryZ | 300 |

I know that Year3 is 2010, Year4 is 2011 and so on, and I have a list of specific tags, not in a table, with their matching categories (one tag can belong to more than one Category).

I need to return a table with the following:

| SubCategoryA | SubCategoryB | SubCategoryC | Year | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2000 | 2900 | 2010 | A |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1550 | 0 | 450 | 2020 | C |

The query I'm trying to improve has the following algorithm:

```
SELECT GROUPA, GROUPB, SUM(
CASE WHEN Tag in ('PrefixYear3.SubCategoryASubSubcategoryA') THEN TRY_CAST([Value] as float)END)
) as SubCategoryA,
...,
'2010' AS Year
'CategoryA' AS Category
GROUP BY GroupA, GroupB

UNION ALL

...

UNION ALL

 SELECT GROUPA, GROUPB, SUM(
CASE WHEN Tag in ('PrefixYear5.SubCategoryASubSubcategoryA') THEN 
TRY_CAST([Value] as float)END) as SubCategoryA,
...,
'2012' AS Year
'CategoryA' AS Category
GROUP BY GroupA, GroupB
```

The way I found to do this is taking a lot more than that solution (three times more):

```
SELECT A.GROUPA, A.GROUPB, 

CASE C.Category
    WHEN 'A' THEN
        CASE B.Year WHEN 2010 THEN [2010 SubCategoryA CategoryA]
        ...
        CASE B.Year WHEN 2012 THEN [2012 SubCategoryA CategoryA]
    END AS [SubCategoryA]
...
CASE C.Category
    WHEN 'C' THEN
        CASE B.Year WHEN 2010 THEN [2010 SubCategoryC CategoryA]
        ...
        CASE B.Year WHEN 2012 THEN [2012 SubCategoryC CategoryA]
    END AS [SubCategoryC]
B.Year,
C.Category FROM
(
SELECT GROUPA,GROUPB,
            sum(CASE WHEN Tag in ('PrefixYear3.SubCategoryASubSubcategoryA') THEN TRY_CAST([Value] as float)END) AS '2010 SubCategoryA CategoryA',
            ...
            sum(CASE WHEN Tag in ('PrefixYear5.SubCategoryASubSubcategoryA') THEN TRY_CAST([Value] as float)END) AS '2012 SubCategoryA CategoryA'
FROM TableA GROUP BY GROUPA, GROUPB)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT      '2010' as [Year]
             UNION
             SELECT     '2011'
             ...) as B
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'CategoryA' as [Category]
    UNION SELECT 'CategoryB'
...) AS C
```

**The answer should be a view.** It means no temp tables, or creating other tables, are valid answers.

Any suggestion on how to do this better is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i can't relate the sampel data with desired output , please provide desired output related to provided sample data

Comment: I'm lost here:  `SUM(PrefixYear3.SubCategoryASubSubcategoryA)`.  I see no such column in any table.

Comment: Hey @eshirvana, the desired output is the second table above, and the two queries below resolve the output. Let me know which part should I explain better :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff My mistake, changed the function to be what it actually is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data and the displayed expected result don't match so there is some guesswork involved, particularly for `category` which isn't in the supplied data, but I believe you can get the required data as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   GroupA  VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL 
  ,Group_B VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,Tag     VARCHAR(39) NOT NULL
  ,Value   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(GroupA,Group_B,Tag,Value) VALUES ('A','E','PrefixYear3.SubCategoryASubSubcategoryA','100');
INSERT INTO mytable(GroupA,Group_B,Tag,Value) VALUES ('B','F','PrefixYear3.SubCategoryBSubSubcategoryA','A');
INSERT INTO mytable(GroupA,Group_B,Tag,Value) VALUES ('C','G','PrefixYear4.SubCategoryCSubSubcategoryZ','300');
```

then this query:

```
select
        SubCategoryA, SubCategoryB, SubCategoryC, Year, GroupA as Category
from (
    select
           *
        , case when tag like '%.SubCategoryA%' then try_cast(value as float) end as SubCategoryA
        , case when tag like '%.SubCategoryB%' then try_cast(value as float) end as SubCategoryB
        , case when tag like '%.SubCategoryC%' then try_cast(value as float) end as SubCategoryC
        , case when tag like 'PrefixYear3%' then 2010
               when tag like 'PrefixYear4%' then 2011
               else NULL
           end as [Year]
    from mytable
    ) as sq
```

which produces this output:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+----------+
| SubCategoryA | SubCategoryB | SubCategoryC | Year | Category |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+----------+
|          100 |              |              | 2010 | A        |
|              |              |              | 2010 | B        |
|              |              |          300 | 2011 | C        |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+----------+
```

*demonstraed at db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=802f11b8a83ace64d6d69ccfb7f88b55)*

Note: I have used `try_cast()` as this will gracefully return NULL if it is unable to return a float from the varchar value.

Comment: Hello. Have you considered this suggestion?